# String.casefold not functioning properly

Tags: python-3.x

When attempting to use specific_string.casefold I get an error.

Whenever I try to concatenate it onto a string for printing (for testing purposes) I get:

```
test = "test"
print("Lowercase: " + test.casefold)
```

> "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str"

Whenever I try to use it as a condition for an if statement it simply glosses over the if statement due to it not being true.

```
test = "test"
if test.casefold == "test" :
    print("test")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax should be `test.casefold()` rather than `test.casefold`. By using `test.casefold` you're attempting to concatenate a string with the function `string.casefold` rather than what would be returned by the function.

Comment: That's exactly my issue. I'm used to languages/IDEs that would automatically add the () to mark it as a function so it just slipped my mind. Thank you